# NSString, what does localizedString mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am sorry if this is an FAQ, but what is the difference between the two statements below? I have been looking on google and also on Apples documentation and I can't seem to find a salid difference. My best guess is the localised one is optimised to be updated at runtime. Could anyone kindly clarify for me?

```
NSString *title1 = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", @"1", @"2"];
```

.

```
NSString *title2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", @"1", @"2"];
```

much appreciated

gary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From NSString Class Reference:

This method is equivalent to using initWithFormat:locale: and passing [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] as the locale argument.

As an example of formatting, this method replaces the decimal according to the locale in %f and %d substitutions, and calls descriptionWithLocale: instead of description where necessary.

This code excerpt creates a string from another string and a float:

`NSString *myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f\n", @"Cost", 1234.56]`;

The resulting string has the value “Cost: 1234.560000\n” if the locale is en_US, and “Cost: 1234,560000\n” if the locale is fr_FR.

[NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/localizedStringWithFormat:)

Answer (score 3):

Read the discussion in the [docs on the method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/localizedStringWithFormat:). It details what it is for. Its purpose is to apply locale formatting, such as correct decimal separators (period versus comma in floating point numbers). Read [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) for more details.